# "Expression has changed after it was checked" when using two instances of the same component

Tags: angular, primeng

The structure of my page:

-- main component

--- component A

------- date picker

--- component B

------- date picker

Date picker's code that causes the error:

```
<div class="input-group" [ngClass]="
               {
               'error': !calendar.valid
               }">
<p-calendar #calendar="ngModel" ...>
```

1) if i remove 'calendar.valid' everything works

2) if i rewrite it like this, everything works:

```
<div>
{{calendar.valid}}
</div>
```

3) or, if i use only one date picker on my page - eveything works

-- main component

--- component A

------- date picker

--- component B

4) or, if i add this code to date picker, everything works:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

EDIT: this error started happening after update from angular 2 to angular 4

Comment: It is expected behavior. It was a bug in angular2

Comment: can you setup a plunker?

Comment: @yurzui I'd like to understand what you mean by "expected behavior". What is it, exactly, that is incorrect about what OP is doing?